# Numerically find cubic polynomial roots where coefficients widely vary in magnitude

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots, machine-precision

Consider the following polynomial:

$$
p(x) = x^3 + (C_b+K_a)x^2 - (C_aK_a + K_w)x - K_aK_w
$$

Where:

- $x, C_a, C_b$ are concentrations, positive real numbers typically within $[10^{-7};1]$. The unknown $x$ is the proton concentration and $C_a, C_b$ are supposed to be constant;
- $K_a$ is acid/base dissociation constant, typically within $[10^{-12},10^{-2}]$;
- $K_w$ is the water ionic product constant which is about $10^{-14}$.

I expect this polynomial to have at least a positive real solution because proton concentration physically exist.

My goal is to find the real positive solution to the equation $p(x)=0$ using some numerical method (Newton, etc. or even Cardano formulae), but I face some normalization problem because of different magnitudes between constants or monomials.

For a typical setup:

$$K_a = 10^{-4.75},\quad C_a = 0.1,\quad C_b = 0.2$$

Polynomial coefficients widely varies in magnitude:

$$
a_3=1.0000,\quad a_2=0.2000,\quad a_1=-1.7792\cdot 10^{-11},\quad a_0=-1.7783\cdot 10^{-24}
$$

The discriminant of this polynomial for this setup is about $\Delta = 5.6905\cdot 10^{-26}$ which is really small, it could be anything: zero, positive or negative, who knows?

I have used both `float` and `fixed decimal` (with 40 decimals) arithmetics to compute those quantities. They slightly differ with the arithmetic kind, but the scaling problem remains. I think my problem is about numerical stability **and normalization**.

Wolfram seems to be able to solve it when I use [symbolic values](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3+%2B+(0.2%2B1e-4.75)*x%5E2++-(0.1*1e-4.75+%2B+1e-14)*x+%E2%88%921e-4.75*1e-14+%3D+0) (answer is correct) instead of [coefficients decimal development](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3+%2B+0.20000000017782795210612252637410752376*x%5E2++-1.7792794100389228999397584572952765430E-11*x+-1.7782794100389228012254211951926848447E-24+%3D+0) (answer is too small).

I am not asking for a complete solution, rather for some hints or references to a method for roots finding for this kind of ill-scaled polynomials. So my questions are:

- How can I accurately solve this kind of polynomial with a numerical method?
- What kind of normalization must I apply before solving it?
- Is there a specific numerical method for this class of problem?

**Nota**

The polynomial $p(x)$ comes from the definition of the acid/base equilibrium constant:

$$
K_a = x\frac{b}{a}, \quad K_w = xy
$$

Where matter amount and charge balances have been injected:

$$
C_a + C_b = a + b,\quad b + y = x + C_b
$$

**Update**

I have managed to find a credible root using [`numpy.roots`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html) and [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) which complies with Wolfram Alpha. The following Python 3 code:

```
import numpy as np
import decimal

Ka = decimal.Decimal("10")**decimal.Decimal("-4.75")
Kw = decimal.Decimal("1e-14")
Ca = decimal.Decimal("0.1")
Cb = decimal.Decimal("0.2")
coefs = [decimal.Decimal(1), (Cb+Ka), -(Ca*Ka + Kw), -Ka*Kw]

r0 = np.roots(coefs)
```

Returns:

```
array([-2.00026673e-01,  8.89021156e-06, -9.99999983e-14])
```

I am still interested to know if there are other care to take in order to properly solve this kind of problems.

Comment: You could try perturbation theory, using the smallest coefficient $a_0$ as the small parameter. Substitute $x = x_0 + a_0 y$ and solve for $y$, where $x_0$ is the solution to the quadratic obtained when $a_0 = 0$.

Comment: For the coefficients given, $(1.0, 0.2, -1.7792\cdot10^{-11}, -1.7783\cdot10^{-24})$, Wolfram Alpha returns solutions $(-0.2, -9.98318\cdot10^{-14}, 8.90598\cdot10^{-11})$. I get very similar solutions out of Kahan's `QBC` solver, using a C++ code that uses `double` arithmetic enhanced by the use of FMA (fused multiply-add): `-2.0000000008896002e-1, -9.9837370721755525e-14, 8.9059837331107879e-11`

Comment: When the coefficients vary rapidly and monotonically it can be improved by scaling your variable.  Here the ratio between the cubic term and the linear term is about $10^{-24}$, so if you replace $x$ by $10^{-8}y$ all the terms will be about $10^{-24}$ and you can divide it out.  Now your quadratic term will be about $10^8$ and the linear one about $10^4$ while the constant and cubic are about $1$.

Comment: Another similar approach is to note that the value of $x$ will be quite small, so the value of $x^3$ will be much smaller than $0.2x^2$,  We can just ignore the cubic term and find that $x$ is of order $10^{-12}$, getting the correct value from the quadratic formula.  The cube of this is $10^{-36}$, which is negligible.  If you really want to incorporate it, write your equation as x=5\sqrt{stuff}$ where stuff comes from the non-quadratic terms and do fixed point iteration starting from the root of the quadratic.

Comment: I did not want to edit once more my answer but, please, notice that my last formula simplifies since $f'''(x_1)=6$. So, $6$ can factor in denominator and $3$ in numerator makes the formula quite nice.

Comment: In my last formula $x_2$ is $x_1$ and $x_1$ is $x_0$. Sorry !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider using Newton method to find the zero of
$$f(x)=x^3+x^2 (\text{Cb}+\text{Ka})-x (\text{Ca} \,\text{Ka}+\text{Kw})-\text{Ka}
  \, \text{Kw}$$
$$f'(x)=3 x^2+2 x (\text{Cb}+\text{Ka})-(\text{Ca} \text{Ka}+\text{Kw})$$
$$f''(x)=6 x+2  (\text{Cb}+\text{Ka})$$ you must not start at $x=0$ since
$$f(0) \,f''(0)=-2\, \text{Ka}  \,\text{Kw}  \,(\text{Cb}+\text{Ka})<0$$ (think about Darboux-Fourier theorem). If you use $x_0=0$, then the first iterate would be
$$x_1=-\frac{\text{Ka} \, \text{Kw}}{\text{Ca}  \,\text{Ka}+\text{Kw}} <0$$

The first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt{(\text{Cb}+\text{Ka})^2+3 (\text{Ca}\,
   \text{Ka}+\text{Kw})}-(\text{Cb}+\text{Ka})\right) > 0$$
 and the second derivative test shows that this is a minimum.

In order to generate the starting point $x_0$, perform around $x=x_*$ (were $f'(x_*)=0$), the Taylor expansion
$$0=f(x_*)+\frac 12 f''(x_*)\,(x-x_*)^2+O((x-x_*)^3 ) \implies x_0=x_*+ \sqrt{-2\frac {f(x_*)}{f''(x_*)}}$$

Using your numbers, Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & \color{blue}{8.8902}609452502354578 \times 10^{-6}\\
 1 & \color{blue}{8.89021155}71665711819 \times 10^{-6}\\
 2 & \color{blue}{8.8902115568921917511} \times 10^{-6}
\end{array}
\right)$$ This is a very reliable procedure.

**Edit**

I am *almost* sure that we could even skip the Newton procedure using a $[1,2]$ Padé approximant built around $x_1$. This would give
$$x_1=x_0+\frac 12\frac{ f(x_0) \left(f(x_0)\, f''(x_0)-2\, f'(x_0)^2\right)}{f(x_0)^2 +f'(x_0)^3- f(x_0)\,f'(x_0)\, f''(x_0)}$$

For the worked example, this would give $x_2=\color{blue}{8.890211556892191751}2 \times 10^{-6}$

Answer (score 2):

According to the [computation on Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3+%2B+(0.2%2B1e-4.75)*x%5E2++-(0.1*1e-4.75+%2B+1e-14)*x+%E2%88%921e-4.75*1e-14+%3D+0) linked in the question, the task is to find the roots of the cubic equation

$x^{3} + (0.2 + 1 \times 10^{-4.75})x^{2}-(0.1 \times 10^{-4.75} + 1 \times 10^{-14})x - (1 \times 10^{-4.75} \times 1 \times 10^{-14})$

If this is representative of the cubic equations that need to be solved, there seems to be no problem in tackling this with IEEE-754 double precision computation and a standard solver, such as Kahan's `QBC` solver:

William Kahan, "To Solve a Real Cubic Equation". Lecture notes, UC Berkeley, Nov. 1986 ([online](https://cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Math128/Cubic.pdf))

I am using Kahan's code pretty much verbatim, but have enhanced it in various places by the use of the FMA (fused multiply-add) operation which is readily accessible from C++ as the standard math function `fma()`. I specified the coefficients as follows:

```
double a3 =  1.0;
double a2 =  0.2 + exp10 (-4.75);
double a1 = -(0.1 * exp10 (-4.75) + exp10 (-14.0));
double a0 = -(exp10 (-4.75) * exp10 (-14.0));
```

The results returned by the `QBC` solver are:

```
-2.0002667300555729e-001
-9.9999998312876059e-014 + i *  0.0000000000000000e+000
 8.8902115568921925e-006 + i *  0.0000000000000000e+000
```

These match the results computed by Wolfram Alpha: $-0.200027, -1.\times10^{-13}, 8.89021\times10^{-6}$

Comment: I don't think that we need to solve the cubic since only the positive root is required.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am not disagreeing, but I think our perspectives may differ: As a software engineer, I tend to look for an existing *proven* approach that can deliver the requested result (call it the cookbook approach, if you will), even if it delivers a bit more than what is strictly needed. Only if I cannot find that do I embark on crafting a custom solution. It seemed to me that in this case, the former approach would work, but it is hard to tell for sure with only a single test case provided.